# English plural of "conundrum"

Tags: etymology, irregular-plurals

A [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600895/is-it-possible-to-bound-a-single-d0-brane-to-a-d4-brane) question had me reading up on D-branes on Wikipedia, where I found the following sentence in [the section on black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-brane#Black_holes):

> The concept of black hole entropy poses some interesting ***conundra.***

I had never seen *conundrum* pluralized this way before. At first I thought it was a [hypercorrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection), and the [citations from Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/conundra) would certainly be consistent with hypercorrection.

The Guardian has [a long (and hilariously contentious) thread on the topic.](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-5253,00.html)

Another blog post from [Ask the League of Nerds](http://asktheleagueofnerds.com/the-conundra-conundrum/) suggests that both are fine but since *conundrum* was a [cod Latin term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_Latin) to begin with, *conundrums* would be the really (*really* really) correct plural.

I thought I'd put the question to this site and get some more scholarly answers (ideally, with citations from reference dictionaries or other reputable sources). **Is there a "correct" English plural of *conundrum*, and if not, which of the two plurals--*conundrums* or *conundra*--is to be preferred in usage?**

Comment: Since the word doesn't get pluralized very often, you can do it any way you like. Which way you choose says more about you than about English grammar (or lexicography).

Comment: I don't have anything to back up my answer with, so I'm posting this as a comment. As R Tanner says in the discussion on The Guardian, [its origin is unknown](https://www.etymonline.com/word/conundrum), so it cannot be pluralised by changing its final syllable to *-dra* because we often use that kind of pluralisation for words that are derived from Latin.

Comment: You have put *correct* in quotation marks, which suggests that you yourself do not think that there really is such a thing as **the** correct (without quotation marks) answer to the question. The question seems to already summarise everything that can be said on the matter; it is unlikely that anybody here will be able to add much to that.

Comment: @jsw29 Right now 1) I don't think that there is a single "correct" plural and the other is "wrong", and 2) I assume *conundrums* is preferable in almost all contexts, except maybe academic ones where people are prone to hypercorrection. But I'm open to hearing other perspectives, and to having my mind changed by a sufficiently persuasive response to the contrary.

Comment: Google Books evidence suggests a more common usage of ***conundrums vs conundra*** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conundrum%2Cconundrums%2Cconundra&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconundrum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconundrums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconundra%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @RiversMcForge, saying that something is a **hypercorrection** implies that it is is misguided, ill-informed attempt at a correction, and thus that it should not be followed, even if others may be prone to it. This is a pseudo-Latin word, so one's choice will ultimately depend on whether one thinks of it as a pseudo-**Latin** word or a **pseudo**-Latin word.

Comment: @jsw29 I said "At first I thought it was" (or began as) a hypercorrection. And, when I say *hypercorrection*, I favor a broad definition that includes e.g. painstakingly rewording a sentence so it doesn't end in a preposition, rather than a narrow sense where the hypercorrection is, strictly speaking, grammatically *in*correct, such as "She invited **Alex and I**". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hypercorrect

Comment: I'd be inclined to use "conundrumline".

Comment: @HotLicks: Is that the only plural in the '-line' category?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul - Is there something you're trying to drum into me?

Comment: I've checked 6 dictionaries in less than 2 minutes. Two give 'conundrums' only as plural; the rest don't think it's worth mentioning a standard-form plural. Though two of these give example sentences with _conundrums_. In spite of the research shown, I feel reasonable research (the above, and [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conundrums%2Cconundra&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconundrums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconundra%3B%2Cc0)) is missing. As Orwell says, don't use the quirky except for effect.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's why this is a question, and not an answer, so that someone can give a more rigorous take :) I don't consider Merriam-Webster and the like *that* much more authoritative than Wiktionary (which, FWIW, the Wiktionary link in the OP does have some further examples of *conundra* in scholarly-seeming published works). If you'd like to give a thoroughly researched and impeccably sourced answer arguing that *conundra* is deprecated or just plain wrong (as opposed to nonstandard/hypercorrect/fussy-sounding), I'd be interested to read it.

Comment: I think the boundaries involved are so nebulous (and hardly worth pursuing; if 98% (latest Google 1gram figures) of people do something one way, why buck the trend? Nothing except a reputation for eccentricity is gained) that I have to CV on a 'merely opinion' ticket.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Makes sense. I wouldn't choose to die on that hill either. Although it is moderately striking to learn, upon verifying your comments, that more than one standard reference (Collins, Oxford) *doesn't even list* conundra *as an option.* Curious....

Comment: English is based on usage, and usage suggests conundrums as the more common form and conumdra as a minor variant. Speculations about Latin or other are not really useful in this case.

Comment: I'll try to slip an answer in before your question gets closed. The question should **not** be closed. If the answer is a matter of opinion, certainly the opinion that matters is expert; likewise, there's only one question.

Comment: @JEL This is essentially generic and could open the floodgates to countless other questions involving variants encountered less than 2% of the time nowadays. Hardly standard English usage.

Comment: @JEL Yeah, I'm a little nonplussed by the close votes because I clarified, in the body of the question and in comments, that I was looking for an authoritative answer from reputable sources, not style advice. Regardless, having this question closed as "opinion-based" is its own kind of answer, right? If the question is whether there is a "correct" plural, or even a preferred one, according to mainstream/expert lexicographic consensus, then saying the answer is "opinion-based" is really saying neither is *definitively* correct, and either one can be used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, what's the cut-off when variants become off-topic? Your statement *seems* to presuppose a horde of aquatic barbarians clamoring to get their wild questions answered at ELU, and the reason you gave for close-voting **this** question smells of what I call 'close-shopping': you claim the question has been researched, but not with the correct tools, and so is likely to elicit answers based on non-expert opinion? I think the answers show otherwise.

Comment: Giving "foreign" words that have been assimilated into English "foreign" plurals is fine as long as you also decline the verb in all the possible grammatical cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[*OED*](https://oed.com/) gives an etymology of 'conundrum'. That etymology starts with "Origin lost", and continues with *expert* speculation and the grounds for the speculation, namely that a 1645 use in an obsolete sense ("pun or wordplay depending on similarity of sound in words of different meaning") mentions the word was used at Oxford: "…which in Oxford they then called conundrums."

'Conundrum' is the only entry in *OED* (3rd Edition; entry not yet fully updated from the 1893 original) with "origin lost" given as etymology. I'm sure that doesn't mean they'll be checking their pockets for it, except perhaps figuratively.

Whether a *spelling* can be correctly described as 'correct', with all the unfortunate denotative baggage that goes along with the term, I'll leave to those with dogs in the fight. For my part, the game's not worth the candle, etc. However, in terms of expert opinion on the appropriate pluralization of 'conundra', *OED* weighs in heavily.

In all of *OED*, 'conundra' appears exactly once, in a [2008](https://archive.org/details/futureofmbadesig0000mold/page/34/mode/2up?q=conundra) quote, attesting the word 'value-ladenness', from *The future of the MBA: designing the thinker of the future*.

> The value-ladenness of theories of behavior (and cognition) is an additional complication to the **conundra** we have discussed previously…

Setting aside the preposterous arrogance of the book title ("MBA" stands for "Master of Business Administration", certainly not a hotbed of future thinker design) and approaching the issue at hand objectively, the pertinent part of the attestation in *OED* is this:

> …conundra [sic]…

So the enormous orthographical and lexicographical weight of *OED* clearly comes down on the side of their avoiding even the appearance of condoning 'conundra'.

'Conundrums', however, appears thick and fast in the historical record *OED* gives for the word. Those of the uses that show the word in plural (which appear at a glance to form the majority), use an ess to pluralize it. Notably also, early uses (sixteenth–eighteenth century) display a bewildering variety of orthographic forms, which all are pluralized, when they are pluralized, with ess.

For the sake of completeness and, more importantly, to oblige my curiosity, I also checked the *Hathi Trust* corpus and [*Early English Books Online*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/t/text/text-idx?ALLSELECTED=1&xc=1&g=eebogroup&type=simple&rgn=full%20text&q1=conundra&cite1=&cite1restrict=author&cite2=&cite2restrict=author&singlegenre=All&Submit=Search&c=eebo&c=eebo2) (EEBO) for occurrences of ['conundrum'](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?a=srchls&q1=conundrum&field1=ocr&anyall1=all&yop=after), ['conundrums'](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?a=srchls&q1=conundrums&field1=ocr&anyall1=all&yop=after) and ['conundra'](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/ls?a=srchls&q1=conundra&field1=ocr&anyall1=all&yop=after) (links for the three words are to *Hathi Trust* results). *Hathi Trust* provides access to digitized works (written in English, Latin and other languages) from "Google, the Internet Archive, Microsoft, and in-house member institution initiatives." EEBO provides access to digitized early English books, primarily from before 1700.

To sum up the results in EEBO, a search for "conundr*" produces 50 results in works printed before 1701; a search in the same corpus for "conundra" produces 0 results.

The results of similar searches at *Hathi Trust* are also interesting. Noting that many *Hathi Trust* results are from different editions or versions of the same original work, the raw numbers are not so immediately telling as simple chronological presence and absence. In the case of 'conundra', discounting false positives and a misdated item, the word does not appear in *Hathi Trust* texts, from any language, before the [1806](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=ien.35556005879267&view=1up&seq=369&q1=conundra) Volume II of *Hogarth Illustrated* (third edition linked; the first edition, printed 1791, presumably also contains the "conundra" anecdote).

> [image: Hogarth's "The Lecture"]
>
> **Datur Vacuum**
> ["Leisure Time", punning on "inanity", "is given"]
>
> "No wonder that science, and learning profound,
> In Oxford and Cambridge so greatly abound,
> When so many take thither a little each day,
> And we see very few who bring any away."
>
> …[a highly accomplished young man, who is considered a model by his fellow-collegians] has not stored his memory with many epigrams, but of puns has a plentiful stock, and in *conundra* is a wholesale dealer.

This use, which is itself jocular, being intended to mock collegians, shows up around 200 years after the first evidence of the singular 'conundrum', which is found in the [1596](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A08003.0001.001/1:8.1?ALLSELECTED=1;c=eebo;c=eebo2;g=eebogroup;rgn=div2;singlegenre=All;sort=datea;subview=detail;type=simple;view=fulltext;xc=1;q1=conundr*#hl1) printing of Thomas Nash's *Haue with you to Saffron-Walden*. In the interim (1596–1791?), many works, from Oxford scholars and others, provide plentiful evidence of the plural 'conundrums'.

Such evidence, or rather such an absence of evidence for early use of 'conundra', argues against an origin of 'conundrum' "as a parody of some Latin term of the schools" (*OED*) although, as *OED* goes on to observe, that origin "would agree with its unfixed form in 17–18th cent." Surely, it seems, those same parodists or their literary heirs might go the whole hog and form the plural on the same alleged base, the contrived neuter Latin noun 'conundrum', that is, as 'conundra'.

The absence of evidence for 'conundra' in early use does not conflict, however, with the other possibility advanced by *OED*, that the origin of 'conundrum' was in "some university joke", which also and more likely "would agree with its unfixed form" in early use.

I suggest, as a more palatable speculation than an origin "as a parody of some Latin term", that 'conundrum' might have been formed as a jocular term on the model of the earlier (1553) reduplicating formation 'humdrum' (also not from Latin).

Finally (I hope), *Hathi Trust* contains only a scant few occurrences of 'conundra' before the advent of widespread quasi-literacy in the 20th century. Only 80 hits result for a search on 'conundra' printed in the years 1807-1901, and many of those (34) represent appearances in various versions and editions of and about Hogarth's works.

In the twentieth century, however, and in my view not coincidentally as expert knowledge of and familiarity with Latin declined, the 'conundra' form shows up with increasing frequency. This is especially true after 1949.

**'Conundra' in Hathi Trust corpus**

| Date Range | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1900-1909 | 6 |
| 1910-1919 | 14 |
| 1920-1929 | 17 |
| 1930-1939 | 18 |
| 1940-1949 | 18 |
| 1950-1959 | 39 |
| 1960-1969 | 48 |
| 1970-1979 | 127 |
| 1980-1989 | 342 |
| 1990-1999 | 636 |

This evidence seems to me to indicate a correlation (which, of course, does not equal causation) between the number of appearances of 'conundra' and the twentieth-century decline of classical education. It suggests that the use of 'conundra', while not a hypercorrection *per se*, is none the less indicative of growing classical ignorance.

Comment: *'Conundrum' is the only entry in OED (3rd Edition; entry not yet fully updated from the 1893 original) with "origin lost" given as etymology* - I feel like this is a subtle play on words on the part of the lexicographers. The origin of *conundrum* is some kind of....mysterious puzzle or enigmatic riddle :P

Comment: *Conundrums* seems more commonsensical and widely attested as the plural form. It's the one I would be inclined to use. But if *conundrum* was indeed originally coined as a nonsense pisstake on highbrow Latin, as some sources suggest, then *conundra* seems like the **funnier** choice, and perhaps the aptest pluralization to the facetious spirit in which the original term was conceived.

Comment: Yes, the conundrum of conundrums. As for correctness, see my position in the answer. That's my position, and I'm sticking to it. However, what's left unsaid is the standard last resort line of prescriptivists: some things work *better* than others to communicate. In the case of a spelling, the over-all familiar and conventional works best, because it stops the hiccups encountered when reading the unfamiliar and unconventional--essentially @EdwinAsforth and others' position in the surrounding. You avoid that with your talk of "preferred"; I avoid it with talk of "appropriate".

Comment: @RiversMcForge I think you're discounting that the origin is unknown (at the least; lost is more like it). An inside joke on the purported inside joke is all well and good, in a context where the joke will be *understood*. In this case, you're relying on people knowing and believing that "origin unknown" is the same as "origin known as a jocular Latin corruption"--which it is not. So yeah, in context, the conundra plural might well be preferrable.

Comment: Sure, we can’t be 100% certain of the origin of “conundrum,” but based on everything we *do* know, the mock-Latin pisstake is by far the most probable explanation. Your comment on “appropriate”/“preferred” usage is exactly what the second part of my question was asking for. I obviously agree that nonstandard *conundra* is eye-catching to the point of distracting some readers, given that coming across it distracted *me* enough to Google it and ask English.SE about it, lol.

Comment: @RiversMcForge, actually, my next bit should cast doubt on that mock-Latin origin, and deservedly. It's a story, but not a particularly convincing one, nor more in consonance with the known facts than other possible stories.

Comment: @jsw29 Thanks; I think so; the notion of *propriety* (as opposed to *appropri*ateness) seems at this time to have been baked into the definition of 'correct', especially in the context of the ongoing prescriptive-descriptive linguistic kerfluffle. The comment by Garner, "If descriptivists believe that any linguistic evidence validates usage, then we must not be descriptivists" sums up my point of view, but at the same time I want to avoid a pointless debate.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks so much for taking the time to put it together.

Comment: I try not to change my green checks once given out, but the meticulous accumulation of well-cited supporting detail in your updated answer on the *conundra* conundrum is fascinating, impressive, formidable, and ultimately persuasive, albeit exhausting and tedious to read all the way through in a single sitting--the trademark paradox of almost all truly high-quality scholarship (*no less than I would expect from someone who spells out the proper name of the letter "S"*). And after reading your edits, what can I say to your counter-theory of *conundrum*'s origin except "Uncle!"?

Comment: I don't wanna study Latin; I just want to bang on a several dra all day.

Answer (score 8):

I checked *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary*, eleventh edition (2003) and the *American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth dition, to see how they recommend handling the plural of *conundrum*. As a rule, neither dictionary lists a plural for noun that end in a standard *-s* form. But both include plural forms when the plural form has some other ending or when there is a significant split in usage.

Here is how these dictionaries treat the plurals of various nouns ending in *-um*:

> **addendum**: *addenda* also *addendums* [MW]; *addenda* [AHDEL]
>
> **album**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **aquarium**: *aquariums* or *aquaria* [both]
>
> **asylum**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **atrium**: *atria* also *atariums* [MW]; *atria* or *atriums* [AHDEL]
>
> **auditorium**: *auditoriums* or *auditoria* [both]
>
> **bacterium**: *bacteria* [both]
>
> **columbarium**: *columbaria* [both]
>
> **compendium**: compendiums* or *compendia* [both]
>
> **consortium**: *consortia* also *consortiums* [MW]; *consortia* [AHDEL]
>
> **conundrum**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **crematorium**: *crematoriums* or *crematoria* [both]
>
> **curriculum**: *curricula* also *curriculums* [MW]; *curricula* or *curriculums* [AHDEL]
>
> **decorum**: no plural listed [MW]; *decorums* [one sense only, AHDEL]
>
> **delirium**: no plural listed [MW]; *deliriums* or *deliria* [AHDEL]
>
> **dictum**: *dicta* also *dictums* [MW]; *dicta* or *dictums* [AHDEL]
>
> **equilibrium**: *equilibriums* or *equilibria* [both]
>
> **forum**: *forums* also *fora* [both]
>
> **geranium**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **gymnasium**: *gymnasiums* or *gymnasia* [both]
>
> **imperium**: no plural listed [MW]; *imperia* [AHDEL]
>
> **magnum**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **maximum**: *maxima* or *maximums* [MW]; *maximums* or *maxima* [AHDEL]
>
> **medium**: *mediums* or *media* [MW]; *media* or *mediums* [AHDEL]
>
> **memorandum**: *memorandums* or *memoranda* [both]
>
> **millennium**: *millennia* or *millenniums* [both]
>
> **minimum**: *minima* or *minimums* [MW]; *minimums* or *minima* [AHDEL]
>
> **modicum**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **momentum**: *momenta* or *momentums* [both]
>
> **moratorium**: *moratoriums* or *moratoria* [both]
>
> **museum**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **opium**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **ovum**: *ova* [both]
>
> **pandemonium**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **pendulum**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **petroleum**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **podium**: *podiums* or *podia* [both]
>
> **premium**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **presidium**: *presidia* or *presidiums* [both]
>
> **quantum**: *quanta* [both]
>
> **quorum**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **rectum**: *rectums* or *recta* [both]
>
> **referendum**: *referenda* or *referendums* [both]
>
> **rostrum**: *rostra* or *rostrums* [MW]; *rostrums* or *rostra* [AHDEL]
>
> **sanctum**: *sanctums* or *sancta* [both]
>
> **serum**: *serums* or *sera* [both]
>
> **stadium**: *stadiums* or *stadia* [MW]; *stadiums* or *stadia* [AHDEL]
>
> **stratum**: *strata* [MW]; *strata* or *stratums* [AHDEL]
>
> **symposium**: *symposia* [MW]; *symposiums* or *symposia* [AHDEL]
>
> **tantrum**: no plural listed both]
>
> **tedium**: no plural listed [both]
>
> **ultimatum**: *ultimatums* or *ultimata* [both]
>
> **vacuum**: *vacuums* *or* *vacua* [both]
>
> **vellum**: no plural listed [both]

This is by no means a complete list of English nouns ending in *-um*. In particular, I have omitted most relevant chemical elements, medical words, and other scientific terms.

Neither dictionary lists *-s* plural forms, but typically they do list irregular plural forms and "foreign" plural forms. Of course, some words (such as *modicum*, *pandemonium*, and *petroleum*) tend not to occur in plural form, so the absence of a plural in those cases should not be taken as an endorsement of a *-s* plural for those words. But other words without a listed plural (such as album, asylum, pendulum, and tantrum) clearly do appear frequently in plural form—and in those instances the absence of a plural indicates that the dictionary views the *-s* form of the plural is the primary or only plural form.

The absence of any plural form in the entry for *conundrum* thus implies that both MW and AHDEL consider *conundrums* to be the only widely used plural form of *conundrum*. It also bear noticing that of the *-um* words listed above, only *conundrum* and *tantrum* fall into the etymological category of "origin unknown." To my mind, this makes them more likely to have a simple *-s* plural form than if they were imports from Latin.

Comment: I'm going to give this answer the green check mark for citing two different sources (albeit some older ones: one of the Wiktionary citations for *conundra* is post-2003) and for putting significant research effort into comparing/contrasting plurals with other *-um* nouns. The consensus seems to be that it's a matter of opinion/personal preference which to use, but your answer seems to imply that *conundra* does not yet enjoy mainstream acceptance or sufficiently widespread usage as compared with *conundrums*.

Answer (score -1):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conundrum

Examples use only "conundrums".

Comment: Please quote a couple of examples they give, as links change and break occasionally.

Comment: As some detailed, carefully researched answers have already been posted on this page, anybody who chooses to post yet another one is expected to make it clear what precisely that answer adds to the existing ones.

Comment: Examples are not what matter, just that the Cambridge Dictionary only uses the plural form "Conundrums". That's my point. And the question asked for "citations from reference dictionaries". Cambridge Dictionary had not yet been referred to. That's my addition. 
But examples follow:

The best shows pose moral conundrums that are hard to solve.

He was perhaps too impatient with overly philosophical conundrums ...
From the Cambridge English Corpus

... attempts at synthesis of archaeological, ... evidence were undermined by ... dating and other interpretative conundrums,

Answer (score -2):

Conundrum is a Latin-based word, and such words can follow Latin pluralization rules. There are several pluralization rules, depending on the word's ending.

In the case of words ending in -um like "conundrum, bacterium, agendum", we can change the ending to -a, coming up with "conundra, bacteria, agenda."

Of course some of these Latin words (like conundrum itself) have been pluralized with the -s ending as well, but still, their Latin plural forms are also valid.

I also found [this](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/latin-plural-endings/) quite comprehensive list of such Latin pluralization rules, that might come in handy.

Comment: I discussed this in the post: *conundrum* is not, strictly speaking, a "Latin word". (Although I guess you could make a case that mock-Latin words are in some sense "Latin-based".) In any case, I'm not convinced that we should always follow Latin pluralization rules for English terms even in cases where Latin etymology is firmly established, as it is not with *conundrum*. A fully persuasive answer would cite reputable dictionaries, lexicographers, grammarians, or other trustworthy sources, and be specific to pluralizing *conundrum,* rather than "Latin pluralization" in general.

Comment: "*Conundrum is a Latin-based word*" /// Is it?

Comment: ... like eardrum, oildrum, kettledrum, humdrum, panjandrum and doldrum?